# How to display "closed" if day is not present in json data?

Tags: json, vue.js, vue-component

```
My json data is in the following way

{"data": {"pid": 80,  "package": 0, "contact": {"email": "a4u@gmail.com", "phone": 472, "address": {"country": "India"}}, "about": "sadfbgmjhmhhgr", "created_at": "2018-01-11", "wrk_hours": [{"opens_at": "08:00:00", "closes_at": "20:00:00", "day": "Saturday"}, {"opens_at": "08:00:00", "closes_at": "20:00:00", "day": "Friday"}, {"opens_at": "08:00:00", "closes_at": "20:00:00", "day": "Thursday"}, {"opens_at": "08:00:00", "closes_at": "20:00:00", "day": "Tuesday"}, {"opens_at": "08:00:00", "closes_at": "20:00:00", "day": "Monday"}], "status": true}
```

Now, I need to display the day and opens_at and closes_at in my page. I need to display from monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday. I need to display all the days. But some days are missing. I f some days are missing, I need to show as closed in place of time. How can I able to implement the same

My current code is

```
<table bgcolor="#00FF00" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#577c14">
      <th v-for="(item,key) in data.wrk_hours" :key="key">
        <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item.day}}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item.day}}</span>
        <span v-else class="all">{{item.day}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item,key) in data.wrk_hours" :key="key">
         <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
        <span v-else >{{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
         </tbody>
                </table>
```

My vue js code is

```
new Vue({ 
 el: '#feed' , 
 data: { 
 data: [], 
 }, 
 mounted() { 

this.$nextTick(function() {    
 $.ajax({ 
 url: "/get/post/", 
 data: {
        pid: pid,
        },
 type: "POST",
 dataType: 'json', 
 success: function (e) { 
 if (e.status == 1) { 
  self.data = e.data;

 } 
 else 
 { 
 console.log('Error occurred');} 
 }, error: function(){ 
 console.log('Error occurred'); 
 } 
 }); 


 }) 
 }, 
 })
```

IN MY JSON DATA, IF SOME DAYS ARE MISIING, I NEED TO DISPLAY IN PLACE OF TIMINGS "closed". I am a beginner and please help me to have a solution? Can anybody please help to have a solution

Comment: Create a computed property `open` that returns a Boolean.

Comment: can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

create an array of `days = ["Sunday","Monday", "Tuesday"...];` then create a function to check if day exists in your array data.wrk_hours, if yes `return {{item.opens_at}} to {{item.closes_at}}` else return "Closed";

```html
<table bgcolor="#00FF00" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr bgcolor="#577c14">
      <th v-for="(item,key) in days" :key="key">
        <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{item}}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{item}}</span>
        <span v-else class="all">{{item}}</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="(item,key) in days" :key="key">
         <span v-if="new Date().getDay()-1==key" class="today">{{ checkIfItemInWorkHours(item) }}</span>
        <span v-else-if="new Date().getDay()==key" class="tomorrow">{{ checkIfItemInWorkHours(item) }}</span>
        <span v-else >{{ checkIfItemInWorkHours(item) }}</span>
    </td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
checkIfItemInWorkHours: function(day){
  for (let x in this.data.workHours) {
    if(this.data.workHours[x].day == day) return `${this.data.workHours[x].opens_at} to ${this.data.workHours[x].closes_at}`;
  }

  return "closed";
}
```

Comment: sir, i did not get your concept